# Using java to checking if a word can be spelt from another word

Tags: java

i'm writing a program using java that checks if a word can be spelt from random given letters in form of a string like if you were playing a scrable game. my problem is if any letter is not found in the random given letters it doesn't do what i told it to do. 
Here is my code for further understanding:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
      canSpell("cenimatography","minato"); 

      /* i get an error for the below, "**String index out of range:-1**" 
         instead of returning can't spell because 'o' is not present.
      */
      canSpell("cenimatgraphy","minato");
    }

   //checks if a word can be spelt from string of letters 
   public static void canSpell(String letter, String word) {

      boolean check=true;

      for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
         if(letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i))!=-1) {
                check = false;
         } else {
            int charLocation = letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i));      
            letter = letter.substring(0,charLocation)+letter.substring(charLocation+1,letter.length());
         }
           check = true;
        }

      if(check) {
         System.out.println("it CAN spell");
      } else {
         System.out.println("it CANNOT spell");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: _"it doesn't do what i told it to do"_, in contrary, it does _exactly_ what you tell it to do. What did you expect it to do though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at the `if/else`:

```
if(letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) != -1) { // The same as assignment of charLocation
    check = false;
} else {
    // charLocation will always be -1 here.
    int charLocation = letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i));
    // Causing the first substring to be out of range.
    letter = letter.substring(0,charLocation)+letter.substring(charLocation+1,letter.length());
 }
```

It looks like it's a typo, and the if statement should should use `==` instead of `!=`.

---

You could make things easier by directly returning this value:

```
public static boolean canSpell(String letter, String word) {
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
         if(letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == -1) { // <-- change to '=='
            return false;
         } else {
            int charLocation = letter.indexOf(word.charAt(i));      
            letter = letter.substring(0,charLocation)
                + letter.substring(charLocation+1,letter.length());
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
if(canSpell("cenimatography","minato")) {
    System.out.println("it CAN spell");
} else {
    System.out.println("it CANNOT spell");
}
```

See [<kbd>Ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/gV9Beq)